# php silently ignoring include on localhost, but not on external server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, include, localhost

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with Apache2 and PHP5.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
\www\
    \index.php
    \parts
         \head.php
         \body.php
```

Inside my index.php I have a command

```
  <?php include("parts/head.php") ?>
```

and the equivalent for body.
These files both exist and they contain more php and html code.

The only thing that shows up when I test the website on localhost (\var\www) is the html outside of the PHP commands. There is no error message, it's as if the file is included but empty.

It is exactly the same as on the website (not localhost) but it works perfectly on the website. I don't understand what is different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is in your browser's address bar for the page that's not working properly?

Comment: http://localhost/codejammers (codejammers being the folder it's in). However, exactly the same happens when I put it straight in the \var\www folder and had http://localhost in the address bar.

Comment: sorry, it auto-formatted the links, if you hover over them it's exactly what I wrote!

Comment: Could you try to `require()` the files instead of including them? Failed `include()` should raise a warning, but execution will continue. Failed `require()` raises a fatal error.

Comment: Also, check the source code - is it possible that your PHP code is not interpreted, but just echoed out to browser? In that case, you need to configure Apache to use the PHP module for processing PHP scripts.

Comment: I didn't see any warning, I'll try swapping to require though. Also, already checked the browser code, and it seems to just be ignoring the include scripts, there's no traces left in the code.

Comment: When I change it to require() I still get no error, but I only get the source code up to just before the require() command. (I've surrounded it with comments so I know where it fails).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have to go now, but I'll add any more information tomorrow and see if I can solve it then.

Comment: @Dom: It sounds like require is erroring out, but PHP is configured not to display errors in the browser.

Comment: @DOM it sounds like when you're reviewing these files on the localhost it's either not through a web-server (`file://...`) or your web-server isn't configured to understand PHP so it isn't interpreting it, just outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file to see if "." is on the path?

You could also try this:

```
include(basename(__FILE__).'parts/head.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always about permissions. When you have something working locally, and then upload and find it doesn't work (include is ignoring file) check the remote files/folders so that you have read/write/execute permissions set as required. (You can do this in FTP) - then run the script again and it should work.